# How to Edit the style of header title of Twenty Eleven Theme?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, theme-twenty-eleven, custom-header

I would like to change the style of Twenty Eleven theme's site title and site description. I tried with style.css file but nothing happens when I refresh the website in a browser. Then I found the main style is already given in index file 58 no line but I did not find any 58 no line in index.php. 
Below I attached a screenshot of this please somebody help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The CSS rule that is setting the color of the site title, which you referred to being on line #58 of index.php (which is actually shown as line #60 in your screenshot), I think, is generated from the WordPress customizer - `Appearance -> Customize` from within your admin area.

The Chrome element inspector isn't referring directly to the `index.php` file (it can't read the PHP files, only the generated/printed HTML). It's actually referring to the HTML page that's generated from the sites PHP code - you can view this, by right clicking and choosing `View Source` or press `Ctrl-U`/`Cmd-U` in Google Chrome.

In order to change the color of the site title, you should be able to change this via `Appearance -> Customize` in your sites admin.

If you'd like to do more advanced customisation of the site title, you would need to target this in the sites `style.css` file. I would, however, recommend doing any CSS customisation in a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), if you're not doing so already (which I get the impression you're not)...

It's important to use Child Themes because if your theme is updated any customisation to the code will be lost. With a Child Theme, your customisations will be maintained.

If you've already made changes to the sites `style.css` file to alter anything (other than the color or any other setting that's generated from the 'Customizer') and they aren't updating on the site, then it's probably a browser cache issue. In this case, clear your browsers cache or try viewing the site in another browser.